# Linq multiple Join with Fix Value

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have the following SQL Query:

```
select      MFSOAM_SubAccountNbr, MFSOAM_Description, 0 as OK, MFSOAM_SubAccountNbr 
from        MFSOAM 
            left join MFSOA on MFSOA_Account=MFSOAM_SubAccountNbr 
            and MFSOA_Acc='1.1.01' 
where       MFSOA_Acc is null 
order by    OK, MFSOA.MFSOA_Account
```

Then I create a Linq from the query above, something like:

```
var model2 = await (from a in _context.Mfsoams
                    join b in _context.Mfsoas on new { a.MfsoamSubAccountNbr } equals new { b.MfsoaAccount, jon = b.MfsoaAcc == request.Account } into ab 
                            from c in ab.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            where c.MfsoaAcc == null
                            select new
                            {
                                Acc = a.MfsoamSubAccountNbr,
                                Desc = a.MfsoamDescription,
                                OK = 0,
                                Acc2 = a.MfsoamSubAccountNbr,
                                Acc3 = c.MfsoaAcc
                            }).OrderBy(o => o.OK).ThenBy(o => o.Acc3).ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

But there's an error on `join` word, it said that join clause is incorrect.

Advise please.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LHS of your equals is of a different type than the RHS of the equals in your join.

The LHS type is of type

```
class LHS
{ 
    int MfsoamSubAccountNbr {get;} 
}
```

The RHS type is of type

```
class RHS 
{
    int MfsoaAccount { get; }
    bool jon { get; }
}
```

There is no obvious way to do EQUALS on these two types.

I suspect you want

```
 var query = from a in _context.Mfsoams
         join b in _context.Mfsoas 
         on new { Account = a.MfsoamSubAccountNbr, MfsoaAcc = request.Account } 
         equals new { Account = b.MfsoaAccount, b.MfsoaAcc } into ab 
         from c in ab.DefaultIfEmpty()
         where c.MfsoaAcc == null
```